# Best Way to Print Case Activities

Tags: civireport, civicase, reports

I've been thinking about different ways to create a report that displays case notes (in other words, case activities). These are the two options I've considered, but with some limitations. How do you, or organizations you work with, tackle this problem?

The options include:

**1. CiviReport** - Use the "Activity Details" report and set the filter: Include Case Activities to "Yes."

- Limitation: Cannot filter case activities by "Case Type." This will be important because one may only want to see case activities by a certain team.
- Printing: Generally, "Print Report" is clean. "Print to PDF" may need some CSS work to display case notes that are really long in length.

**2. Drupal Views** - Create a View with the CiviCRM Activities. Use filter to expose criterias (e.g., Case Type, etc).

- Limitation: None other than printing.
- Printing: Some clients may have 800+ case notes. Currently, I do not believe there is a way to print multiple pages.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ad your Views solution: use Views PDF for the printing; it can do multiple pages; it can print on a template (if you require letterhead/stationary look);

For a how-to - check my notes here on how to generate a Membership Certificate: [How can Members download their own Membership Certificate/Card?](https://civicrm.stackexchange.com/questions/20241/how-can-members-download-their-own-membership-certificate-card)

Answer (score 1):

This may or may not meet your requirements, but it's worth noting that there are 2 built-in "print case activities" options currently in CiviCase. You can click the "Print Report" button from the manage case screen, which will print all activities in the main timeline, or you can get finer control from the "Activity Audit" menu which lets you select a timeline and gives you further redaction options before printing.

[image]

Comment: When I go to "Print Report", for some reason, the activities are not showing and gives me an error: Warning: DOMDocument::loadXML(): Empty string supplied as input in CRM_Case_Audit_Audit->getActivities() (line 33 of C:\xampp\htdocs\sites\all\modules\civicrm\CRM\Case\Audit\Audit.php).

Answer (score 1):

Another possibility if there's nothing in Civi that meets your requirement is to use a reporting tool like Reportico. If you are OK with using SQL then this should do it. It's open source and well supported. Their website is [Reportico.org](http://Reportico.org)

Comment: Adding a 3rd party reporting library can lead to issues. If you use direct SQL then your reports may break when you update CiviCRM so I wouldn't recommend this unless you are very confident that you can maintain your reports...

Comment: True, Jamie - as I said you need to be 'OK with using SQL'  But some SQL I put together in Access in 2013 that accessed Civi's database remotely was still good for a Reportico report in 2017.