# How can Members download their own Membership Certificate/Card in Drupal 7?

Tags: drupal, civimember, drupal-views

This is a request I get quite often. Below is my favourite solution for it.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

No custom code required! If you're on Drupal Views integration, which ships with CiviCRM - all that's required here are Drupal modules Views, Views PDF and installation of two libraries for the PDF generation: tcpdf and fpdi;

**Here are the steps:**

1. **First we will create a Membership tab** in your Drupal `/user` screen where we will display the relevant Membership details pulled from CiviCRM:

[image]

**To create this Membership Tab:**

**a) setup your CiviCRM - Drupal CMS integration** by following the instructions here:
Administer -> System Settings -> CMS Database Integration
direct link: `civicrm/admin/setting/uf?reset=1`
This makes the CiviCRM tables available in your Drupal Views.

**b) on the Drupal side** - enable Drupal Views; and Create a new View - key elements are Relationships -> connecting CiviCRM Contact w/ Drupal user ID and Contextual Filter -> so we can create a path `user/%/membership` and the Menu item: Tab: `Membership`

**c) here is a complete Views configuration for the Page:**

[image]

**2. Hitting the Download Membership Certificate link produces:**

[image]

**To create this Certificate (a PDF download):**

**a) you need to download and install module: Views PDF** -> which requires libraries: tcpdf and fpdi -> put them in a `/libraries folder` that is accessible by your site - either `sites/default/libraries` or `sites/all/libraries`.

**b) when installed -> add a new display in your View -> of type PDF Page.** I've selected PDF fields -> in Settings you can: upload and select a background template of your choice; you can also specify an offset X and Y for each of the CiviCRM variables to position them exactly where you want them!

[image]

**c) In your PDF Page View -> Note the path:**

[image]

**d) Now that you've made the PDF Page display:** add a Field on your `user/%/membership` page -> Custom text -> e.g. Download Membership Certificate. Hit Rewrite Results -> select Output this field as a link as follows:

[image]

Comment: Excellent write up. For newbies, you can also set this up as a Block in sidebar left so it is obvious without needing to go to the Tab

Comment: Yes add a display: block and use Drupal to position in which ever region and on whatever URL you want!

Comment: Nice write up. How can adopt this for an event participants? Thanks

Comment: Also can this be automated with civirules, so that when a participant is marked as “Attended” they would receive an email with this views link?