# Creating Event Participation Certificate in PDF

Tags: email, pdf

I've seen posts with something similar but I am a bit lost. What I am trying to do is to add some automation in creating certificates to participants of an event.  Our events are training sessions and we issue a certificate to those that attend.  Here is what I'm trying to accomplish:

User is registered to attend the event
At the conclusion of the event, we confirm registrations to those who actually attended. We update the records to those as "Attended".

Those that "Attended" would then get a certificate e-mailed to them.

Our certificates have a certain format with a border and a paragraph about the program. There is also a signature image on the certificate.   Is there a way to have this certificate template in CiviCRM and with "Display Name" as a token and have the certificates generated from the "Attended" list and then e-mail them?  It would be similar to PDF receives and PDF letters...just a preformatted certificate.

Comment: I apologize for not stating it. I am on Joomla. With that, the link you provided is exactly what I'm looking for..except in Joomla.

Comment: :-( that’s unfortunate...

Answer (score 4):

If you’re on Drupal then you can do this with Views Integration -> here is a tutorial with steps and screenshots on how to create a downloadable Hogwarts Certificate:

[How can Members download their own Membership Certificate/Card?](https://civicrm.stackexchange.com/questions/20241/how-can-members-download-their-own-membership-certificate-card)

Instead of pulling in Membership data -> pull in Event/Participant data and status.

Comment: Hi thanks for the answer. I also had a same question as OP. Your answer on the other thread seems to be for a membership certificate and not for an event. What would needed to be done differently if I follow yours?

Comment: You would just need to create a View of Participants as opposed to of Memberships.