# Preventing CiviMail from Resizing Images for Membership Cards

Tags: civimail

Because of Covid-19 restrictions, our men's group isn't printing and laminating membership cards for 2021. Instead I'm trying to use CiviMail to send a facsimile of the card(s) that the member can print and clip. The cards provide merchant discounts, so many members want to have them. I overprint member name and other information on a blank member card image.

My problem is that the html/css I prepare gets modified (augmented for responsiveness?) by CiviMail when it sends the mailing.

i.e. **shrinktofit="true"** is added to an image class that I want to not scale so that it's viewable

here's the html in the CiviMail editor window

div class="polaroid"><img alt="Member Card" src="https://../sites/default/files/civicrm/persist/contribute/images/LMGA-Logo%20Membership%20Cards%202021.jpg" style="width:100%"

becomes the following in the sent email

div class="polaroid"><img alt="Member Card" **shrinktofit="true"** src="https://../sites/default/files/civicrm/persist/contribute/images/LMGA-Logo%20Membership%20Cards%202021.jpg" style="width:100%"

I'd like to disable this automatic scaling for this particular mailing. Is that a possibility?

Comment: If you're on Drupal -> here's how you can get Members to download their own Membership Certificates/Cards -> https://civicrm.stackexchange.com/questions/20241/how-can-members-download-their-own-membership-certificate-card

Comment: It is Drupal - This may be exactly what I needed. I'll check it out!

Comment: OK, it is EXACTLY what I need, and the link is very detailed and terrific, especially to extend to a screenshot of the view. However, I find that I can't find the fields and relationships that the view requires, and that makes me realize I'm apparently deficient in my knowledge of views and Civi/Drupal integration - specifically, here's where I'm stuck: --------enable Drupal Views; and Create a new View - key elements are Relationships -> connecting CiviCRM Contact w/ Drupal user ID and Contextual Filter -> so we can create a path user/%/membership and the Menu item: Tab: Membership

Comment: continued...specifically, here's where I'm stuck: - quoting from the instructions "enable Drupal Views; and Create a new View - key elements are Relationships -> connecting CiviCRM Contact w/ Drupal user ID and Contextual Filter -> so we can create a path user/%/membership and the Menu item: Tab: Membership" I've begun to create the view, but can't find the fields I need (e.g. (Drupal User) CiviCRM Contacts: Display Name, etc. - I realize I'm supposed to create or use relationships and contextual filters, but I'm unsure of the steps. Any ideas?

Comment: Relationships and Contextual Filters - are showing in the View screenshot that I posted. Look on the right hand side.

Comment: Thanks Karin - yes I saw them (and thanks so much for the screen grab - very helpful!), but I don't seem to have the filter or the relationship available from the pulldown. I'm on D7.73 and possibly these are available in D8 or in some other way I've got to find and install them. Sorry to be so dense!

Comment: Those screenshots are D7 

Comment: Thanks again Karin - I'm not a D8 user and didn't know the screen shot was a giveaway of the version. My issue is that the contextual filter pulldown doesn't show "CiviCRM Drupal match table ... "  or any other CiviCrm... filters. And the Relationships pulldown doesn't have "CiviCRM Contacts Drupal ID" , and thus I don't have the required fields in the add fields pulldown. Probably I'm missing some required module?